# Al realizar consulta usando count() y groupBy(), el resultado devuelve el mismo valor para todos los registros

Tags: laravel

Verán, estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en laravel en la cual pueda hacer un conteo de los registros repetidos y mostrar el número de veces que se repite cada uno, al hacer la consulta en la base de datos mysql, funciona bien:

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(`departamento`) FROM `asistencias` GROUP BY `departamento`
```

Y obtengo el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona bien, el problema es cuando hago la consulta en laravel de la siguiente forma:

```
$departamentos_count = Asistencia::select('departamento')->groupBy('departamento')->count();
```

Me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería de ser:
[3,5,2,6,6,4]

Al parecer solamente me lee el primer valor y repite el mismo para el resto de los registros.

Comment: Va un ejemplo: ´$users = DB::table('cuentas as a')
    ->join('pasajeros as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.pasajero_id')
    ->where('b.usuarios_id', $id)
    ->withCount('nombre_de_tu_relacion')
    ->first();´ prueba con ´withCount´

Comment: @NahuelJakobson en la consulta no hay ningún join, luego entonces por qué proponerlo?, tampoco lucen necesarias las relaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifíca tu consulta de está forma:

```
$departamentos_count = Asistencia::select('departamento')
                                 ->selectRaw("COUNT(departamento")
                                 ->groupBy('departamento')
                                 ->get();
```

Lo que hacemos es:

- Pasar la función de agregación de forma literal con `selectRaw`
- Hacemos uso de `get` para obtener la colección de los registros deseados
- Quitamos el método `count` pues este nos devolverá un renglón nada más con el conteo pero no la agrupación como se busca